# Clean outputDir except some files

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I am using Vue.js with vue-cli and currently in my package.json before every script I am running `clean` script to clean all build files except `app.php` and `.htaccess` files:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "npm run clean && vue-cli-service build --mode development --watch --no-clean",
    "dev": "npm run clean && vue-cli-service build --mode development --no-clean",
    "build": "npm run clean && vue-cli-service build --no-clean",
    "clean": "find ../outputDir/* -not -name 'app.php' -not -name '.htaccess' -delete"
  }
```

This is working fine on Linux OS but not on macOS and Windows. Is there any better solution to keep some files in **outputDir** so it will be stable on all OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your folder structure to something like this:

```sh
OutputDir
├── app.php
└── static
    ├── index.js
    └── otherOutput.js
```

and then point your vue output to `OutputDir/static`, then you will not need `--no-clean` option and it will only delete the files inside the `OutputDir/static` and not `OutputDir` hence your app.php will be untouched. This should work on all platforms.